# findByIdAndUpdate not failing even when body contains params not in schema

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

Taken from [This MERN tutorial](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/the-mern-stack-tutorial-building-a-react-crud-application-from-start-to-finish-part-2-637f337e5d61)...

I have a mongoose schema with 4 fields:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Todo = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },  
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },  
    comments: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },  
    done: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    },  
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', Todo);
```

I'm calling this `update` route:

```
todoRoutes.route('/update/:id').post(function(req, res) {
    Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.status(400).send('Updating item failed: ' + err);
        else
            todo.save().then(todo => {
                res.json('Item updated!');
            }).catch(err => {
                res.status(400).send("Update not possible: " + err);
            }); 
    }); 
});
```

with the following body:

```
{
    "name": "bla"
}
```

and gets an "ok" status, and the document is updated as I wanted. However, running the same `update` with an extra field, also gets an "ok" status, though it should have failed IMO:

```
{
    "name": "bla",
    "unwanted_field": true
}
```

- The field is not shown when I `GET` the DB, but it still returns without any error. Why?
- Why update does not require the "required" fields, and accepts any updates?

Comment: Mongoose filters properties not in the schema, at least when `strict` mode is enabled (by default) on the schema.

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) has a `strict` option, that can be used like this:

```
let Todo = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },  
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },  
    comments: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },  
    done: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    },  
},
    { 
        strict: true // This is true by default. Changing this to "throw" will throw an error, as shown in the image attached.
    }
);
```

I add here an image of an error I got using postman, trying to add bad data after adding the `strict: "throw"` option:

[image]